# How to make a model's column optional with uniqueness constraint in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am interested in adding optional column `new_column_id` to an existing active record model by
`belongs_to :new_column, optional: true`. I also want to ensure the values of the `new_column_id` are unique in the existing active record model.

I tried `validates :new_column, uniqueness: true`, but it seems that it requires `new_column_id` to always exist in the existing active record model.

What would be the best way for me to add the optional field with uniqueness database constraint?

Comment: @Alex Thanks for your prompt help on this! Now I have no errors - made my day!

Comment: You probably still want to add a uniqueness constraint in the database to ensure that on a database level too

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the best way for me to add the optional field with uniqueness database constraint?

The [ActiveRecord uniqueness validation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) has nothing to do with database constraints. It's an application level validation that does a SQL query to check if there are existing records and [as such it's prone to race conditions](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/the-perils-of-uniqueness-validations).

The validation merely serves to catch *most* duplicate values on the application level and provide user feedback instead of having a database driver error be raised. If uniqueness is actually important you need to add a database level constraint in a migration.

```
# YMMV across RDBMS
# NULL is unique in the SQL standards but may not always be so
add_index :table_name, :new_column, unique: true
```

If you want to allow nil's through the validation you use the `allow_nil` option:

```
validates :new_column, 
   uniqueness: true,
   allow_nil: true
```